# Missing fonts when exporting PDF from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

I'm trying to export a PDF from InDesign and there are a few fonts 
which are missing (they are replaced with another font). I don't have the fonts installed (in `Windows/Fonts`), is this the issue? Do I have to install them? Somebody told me that InDesign is using the fonts from Windows.

Comment: If the font is not stored installed on your machine then yes InDesign will have a tough job finding the font. Best to look online for the font your after and simply install. If it's not free then find a free alternative font to use.

Comment: Another way to make fonts available in Indesign (but not in the Windows system) is to add any font files you wish in a "Document fonts" folder which should be in the same location as your INDD source. This way any font in that folder is available to use in your document without having to install in Windows fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're missing fonts you'll either have to install them or replace them. InDesign will warn you of missing fonts in a couple of ways:

1. It'll highlight text in pink: [image]
2. You'll be warned when you attempt to export the PDF
3. You can use the Find Font dialogue box under *Type > Find Font.* This will list all the fonts used in the document, and flag any that are missing.

Once you've established which fonts are missing, you can attempt to source them and install them on your system. Presumably the InDesign file was created on a different machine with different fonts: if you/someone else can open up the document again on the *original* machine and use the *File > Package* option, it will create a folder with the relevant font files, which you can then install.

If you can't source them, you can replace them with similar fonts using the Find Font dialogue:

[image]

1. Missing fonts are marked with an yellow warning icon.
2. To replace the font, click on the font name to select it, and then select a font to replace it with from the drop-down menu.
3. You then have the option to *change all* the text throughout the document, or you you can use the *find* options to go through the document and *change* one occurrence at a time.